# (JButton) size of button in new window in JAVA GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am using `setBounds()` method on my button to set the size and location of the button . After running, the size of the button is taken up all the frame. Here's my source code

```
public class Main {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton cal = new JButton();
    
    public Main() {
        
        cal.setText("Calculate");
        cal.setBounds(150, 50, 100, 100);
        cal.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Calculate"));
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.setTitle("Calculation Program");
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(cal);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }
}
```

And [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFZd9.png)

I would like to know how can I possibly set the size to it actual?

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: (1-) *I am using setbounds()* - don't! You don't know what the proper size of the component should be based on the Font and text. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. The tutorial examples will also show how to better structure your code to make sure components are created on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use the tutorial for Swing basics.

Comment: `cal = new JButton("calculate")` have you heard of the [setText](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)) method?

Comment: Also I have written all the code for you (You will see it once it gets approved), please avoid pictures of code in your future questions :>

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your button is in the correct position you need to set Layout Manager sutable for your situation. By default Swing uses FlowLayout wich will put your objects one after another. You can check MigLayout. This Layout is easy to use and it is very versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Let me point out a *few* mistakes in your code and question in general.

1. Using `setBounds()`. It's just plain wrong. There is no point in having to be so specific every time you create a component, its unecessary, a waste of time and effort. There are so many [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that you are provided with just take advantage of that.
2. However if you still want to use `setBounds()` because you are a menace to Swing you should remember you can't use `setBounds()` without setting layout to `null` with `frame.setLayout(null)`. Trying to use the `setBounds` method without setting the `null` layout just won't work.
3. Using images instead of copying the code here on StackOverflow. I had to  manually copy this code line by line from an image wasting my time just so I could run it, please avoid using [pictures of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) as pointed out by [Diego Borba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145322/jbutton-size-of-button-in-new-window-in-java-gui#comment135999190_77145322)

Instead of hard coding the position and sizing of your button (which is pointless as it will retain the same position from the top left corner of the JFrame) just use [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) because

- It can keep the orientation no matter the size of the parent component
- It is really customizable
- It is also really easy to understand

Taking this into consideration let's see how we can implement this in your code!

```java
public class Main {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton cal = new JButton();
    
    public Main() {
        
        cal.setText("Calculate");
        cal.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Calculate"));
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setTitle("Calculation Program");
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(cal);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }
}
```

Incase you want to change the size of your button use `setPreferredSize()` like so

```java
...
cal.setText("Calculate");
cal.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Calculate"));
cal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,500));
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add this line to your code:

```java
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Then it works.
You need to set the layout to null, because the default value when you init the JFrame is `BorderLayout` and this breaks you `setBounds` input.

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The solution is to use the "proper" layout managers based on the requirements.